# Azure function blob storage file name

Tags: python, azure, azure-functions, azure-blob-storage

When using azure functions with blob storage output bindings, how do you get the created blob's name, path or URL? I want to save this to a DB once it saved it.

Im using Python, but any example will do:

```
blob = open(os.environ['outputBlob'], 'wb')
blob.write(attachment.get_payload(decode=True))

print blob.name # this is not the correct name, but actually the temp file name I think

blob.close()
```

Comment: Try enumerating the environment variables that are exposed to your function - you may find more data about your blob there.

Comment: Hi @Harry, have you solved the issue as yet?

Comment: @BoitumeloDikoko Did you manage to solve it!? :)

Comment: Rather than using the blob storage output bindings, I am wondering about using the blob storage python SDK to do the job from within the function...

Comment: @jtlz2 I ended up using a C# blob triggered function which writes to storage queues, then using python storage queue trigger function to read the path. This isn't optimal hence now we have moved to writing most of our functions in C#, as the support for python is limited.

Answer (score 0):

For C# :
As discussed at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-storage-blob#input you can use below type of blob bindings

[image]

Below is example of binding json file and the code. I am returning outpuBlob.Uri in http return to get the primary location path of Blob.

Bindings:-

```
{
  "bindings": [
    {
      "authLevel": "function",
      "name": "req",
      "type": "httpTrigger",
      "direction": "in",
      "methods": [
        "get",
        "post"
      ]
    },
    {
      "name": "$return",
      "type": "http",
      "direction": "out"
    },
    {
      "type": "blob",
      "name": "outputBlob",
      "path": "outcontainer/{rand-guid}",
      "connection": "AzureWebJobsDashboard",
      "direction": "inout"
    }
  ],
  "disabled": false
}
```

Function Code (C#):

```
#r "Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage"

using System.Net;
using Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Blob;

public static async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Run(HttpRequestMessage req, TraceWriter log,CloudBlockBlob outputBlob)
{
    log.Info("C# HTTP trigger function processed a request.");

    // parse query parameter
    string name = req.GetQueryNameValuePairs()
        .FirstOrDefault(q => string.Compare(q.Key, "name", true) == 0)
        .Value;

    if (name == null)
    {
        // Get request body
        dynamic data = await req.Content.ReadAsAsync<object>();
        name = data?.name;
    }



    return name == null
        ? req.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, "Please pass a name on the query string or in the request body")
        : req.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, "Hello " + outputBlob.Uri);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I assume python does not have this at its disposal :-(

Comment: @Thomas.. he clearly stated any example will do. so i gave C# example so that he can look for similar ones in python.

Comment: @Harry - Did you try to install python storage modules and try to refer those into your .py file. you can install it as said below https://github.com/yokawasa/azure-functions-python-samples/blob/master/docs/install-python-modules.md

Comment: So where are the python blob-binding types specified?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the environment variables in your Python script's process space. You should have one that contains the path of the blob binding.

Comment: What is the name of the relevant environment variable?

Comment: Not sure what exactly the pattern is. However, Python functions on Functions v1 (which uses this environment variable model) have been deprecated. If you're interested in writing Python functions, take a look at the Python support on Functions v2, which is a complete rewrite: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-reference-python